# `right join`ing a `meta` table the right way

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables in my DB:

```
user_post:
id   user_id   title      date_added
12   220       the post   2019-02-12

user_post_meta:
id   post_id   post_key  post_value
2    12        desc      this is a description
3    12        image     http://img.com/img.jpeg
```

I'm trying to write a query that should fetch all `posts` by `user_id`, also joining & returning all rows from `user_post_meta`. But joining would only return last row in `post_meta`

```
        SELECT
            up.id as up_id,
            upm.post_key as upm_post_key,
            upm.post_value as upm_post_value
        FROM `user_post` up
        RIGHT JOIN `user_post_meta` upm
            ON upm.`user_post_id` = up.`id`
        WHERE up.user_id = 220
```

The above query would only return me the last row of `post_meta`, obviously what I have in where would nullify the `Right join`.

What is the right way to return all results from `user_post_meta`?

**EDIT**

I had a `group by` clause for another join table in the query above(which I didn't mention) that was causing the issue. So, the question can be deemed irrelevant.

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN. Just sayin'. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: that was a stupid question. idk why I asked that. I had a group by for another table (which I didn't mention above) that was causing the issue

Comment: You seem to have accepted an answer which, by your own admission, you believe to be irrelevant to the problem at hand. I think this might create confusion for others. A more reasonable strategy might be simply to delete the question.

Comment: @Strawberry I cannot delete this question (SO won't let me), but may be I could edit the question and point out the irrelevancy myself

Comment: I suspect that you would first have to unaccept the answer. But if you still can't delete, then another strategy might be to provide a suitable answer, and accept that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use LEFT JOIN.

Why?
on your post RIGHT JOIN, you are making your user_post_meta  as the MAIN table of the structure (point of view). The logic is way off the goal you trying to achieve.

```
LEFT JOIN `user_post_meta` upm
            ON upm.`user_post_id` = up.`id`
```

Is the proper way to do it.

Comment: that was a stupid question. idk why I asked that. I had a group by for another table (which I didn't mention above) that was causing the issue. thanks anyway mate.

Comment: btw, is there any way to apply `group by` for just one table and not the other...? just wondering, if there's way to do that

Comment: you perform GROUP BY on a logical sense if you are pointing to a column as the starting point of your query. 
LEFT JOIN a table the records become optional.  You can group by on it, but you have to be aware that the LEFT JOIN table has NULL records if the relations doesnt exist.   
No definite answer, but it only depends on the records and the expectations.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN are entirely interchangeable. However, because humans tend to find RIGHT JOIN rather counterintuitive, it's rarely used.